# Is it possible to create this drop shadow just with plain CSS3?

Tags: css

Our designers have a fetish for fancy drop shadows like these but I want to avoid using image sprites. Instead I'd like to create this with css3 only. It's a little tricky though to replicate it pixel-perfect just with css3:

[image: Fancy drop shadow]

This is the closest I could get but I am not really happy with the result because I don't want the extra html wrapper for .box and also the fade effect to the left doesn't look right:

[image: My attempt]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/valmar/k8ugjwb2/3/

My code attempt:

```css
body{
    background: #edefed;
}

.boxwrap{
    width: 350px;
    height: 365px;
    position:relative;
}

.box{
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background: #fff;
}

.box:after{
    width: 350px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 26px;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    content: " ";
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 16px 21px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.56);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 16px 21px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.56);
    box-shadow: 0px 16px 21px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.56);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="boxwrap">
   <div class="box">content</div>
</div>
```

Is there any css guru out there who can create a pixel-perfect replica of this drop shadow without any extra markup than `<div class="box">content</div>`?

Comment: Can you please suggest whats need to be the output.

Comment: @stanze What do you mean by output?

Comment: You could have a blurred, transparent, rotated 'box' underneath the actual box which has a linear gradient to give the fade-out effect on the left. It doesn't simplify the `html`, but at least should look more like the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, pixel-perfect is a hard requirement.

Bu I can show you a way, and leave it quite close. I am using a pseudo element, with 2 radial gradients, and a rotation.

You can play with the relative positions of the gradients, the colors, and the stops to fine tune it.

```css
#testback {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 210px;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  z-index: 1;
}
#test {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  width: 94%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 3%;
  z-index: auto;
}
#test:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 81%;
  height: 61px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 1%;
  transform: rotate(-4deg);
  z-index: -1; 
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgb(82, 82, 82), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 60%),                         radial-gradient(ellipse at center, gray, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 70%);
  background-position: 14px 0px, center center;
}
```

```html
<div id="testback">
<div id="test">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see no drop shadow in your demo

Comment: @Timo It works for me in Chrome, IE and FF. May be you are using Safari ?

Comment: Oh, yes. Why does it not work in Safari? Looks good on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/k8ugjwb2/4/)

```
.box:after{
    width: 350px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 26px;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    content: " ";
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0px 19px 8px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.56);
}
```

Comment: Looks even worse because the drop shadow is not rotated